# C++ unknown type name due to circular dependency

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

C++ newbie here. I currently have two classes that depend on one another. Class A composes a data member of Class B, while Class B uses pointers to Class A.

```
// main.cpp 
#include "A.hpp"

// A.hpp
#pragma once
#include "B.hpp"

class A {
    private:
        const B obj;
};


// B.hpp
#pragma once
#include "A.hpp"

// forward declaration
class A;
using T = A;

class B {
    private:
        T* t_obj;
};
```

My understanding is that the preprocessor will enter `A.hpp` first, then enter `B.hpp` immediately. It will not be able to enter `A.hpp` again because of `#pragma once`, and will resume with `B.hpp`. Then it will hit the forward declaration and so `class B` should be OK. Then, `A.hpp` will resume and `class A` should be OK.

However, the compilation error I get is something like:

```
 ./A.hpp:5: error: unknown type name 'B'
        const B obj;
```

Any sort of insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Remove `#include "A.hpp"` in B.hpp

Comment: I could do that, but in `B.cpp` I have a method that `delete`s `t_obj` and I get a compiler warning that says: `deleting pointer to incomplete type 'T' (aka 'A') may cause undefined behavior
      [-Wdelete-incomplete]`. Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies, I seem to answer my own question. I need to include `#include "A.hpp"` in `B.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

`main.cpp` should be fine with the explanation given up there by yourself. However, you mention in a comment that you have a `B.cpp`!? My guess would be that the error you cite actually happens during compilation of `B.cpp` and not `main.cpp`. If `B.cpp` includes `B.h`, then the preprocessor will include `B.h` which will include `A.h`. And `A.h` will try to include `B.h`, but since `B.h` already has been included at that point, the compiler will skip that include due to `#pragma once` and you enter the definition of `class A` without having seen a definition of `class B`…